# Gantt Chart Web Part: '[Column]' already belongs to this DataTable

Tags: 2010, column, chart-web-part, microsoft-access, gantt-view

I ran into an issue in vanilla Sharepoint 2010 where I had a gantt chart set up on a page and another user modified it, forcing me to recreate the chart. I went to connect the new chart to data through a list like before but it prompts me with a correction I need to make. It says:

> "Please correct the following:
> • A column named 'Workspace' already
>   belongs to this DataTable."

I know for a fact I did not create this column and it only shows up if I open my list in Access but I cannot delete the column and it does not have an associated relationship with any other list item. Without removing or modifying this column somehow, my chart will not display any data correctly. Because of who I work for, I am restricted to vanilla SP10 and cannot use any code or third party software.

Please advise... Thank you!